# Replicate a 3d striped effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, illustrator-effects

How would you replicate this 3d striped effect? I'm thinking about revolving some shape and mapping a striped symbol onto it, but this shape looks more complicated than that. 
[image]

Comment: What you got so far?

Comment: please [edit] your question to add what have you tried, perhaps a screenshot of your progress. The shape looks complicated because it was probably produced with a 3D software.

Answer (score 3):

Closest I can get to make something like this would be to use Blend tool. You can make two shapes and blend them together, twist and turn the path, play with opacity and brush profile. 
[image]
[image]

Check this quick video I did.
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGcKwbYm4A8)

Comment: It isn't exactly like the posted example, but it's a very nice result and very simple to make! You should explain how to do it with words and/or record a gif you can post here. One day your Youtube link will die and the answer will lack an explanation.

Comment: I tried my best to explain it in the words. See,  "Exactly" is a big word when it comes to graphic design, and as mentioned above, you will have to PLAY around, like stroke size, color, gradients, transparencies to get as close to the posted image. Voice overs and GIF are totally not necessary at this point I believe, video is very straight forward. Thanks :)

Comment: With "explain" I mean a thorough step by step explanation. "Select object this. Click button that" etc. Your video will be understood even by newbies, but it's better to include a gif in the post itself, so the answer doesn't go obsolete when you one day choose to delete the video.

Comment: I agree that "exactly" is a "big word", but I think the posted example involves some kind of 3D graphics. It has some basic shadowing and the lines seems to have 3D thickness. Anyway, aesthetically I like your result way better than the posted example!